# How do I center elements in a div, along a baseline, without a container?

Tags: html, css

How can I center the content within the div, but keep the 3 `p` elements left-aligned? I am not able to add an additional 'container' div.

I want it to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtRdW.jpg)

```css
div {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100px;
  
  /* this does not align all <p>'s to the left, but does center them */
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, foo</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In your case the <p> tags are the content, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can text-align: left and anything else you add in the div you can try margin:0 auto; (depending on what and how you add it, the solution may vary)

Comment: Two options that I came by - not very beautiful, but to do it normally you do want a container.
1). add `padding-left: 40%;` to your div. That will push the `p`s to the center. 
2). add `margin-left:40%` to the  `p`s. Same thing - they will push themselves to the center

You can change the percentage ofc to choose the desirable position

Comment: Add padding in the container div is probably the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS grid:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}



p {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum, foo</p>
</div>
```